# Using "let" in javascript in terms of browser compatibility?

Tags: javascript, backwards-compatibility, polyfills

What are the options for using the `let` keyword in javascript. It seems like it would be really useful.

I've seen [traceur](http://traceur-compiler.googlecode.com/git/demo/repl.html), but I'm wondering if there are any other options, so I don't have to run entire projects through it.

Is it even possible with some type of polyfill or library. Or do I basically have to wait until all the old browsers die out to use it natively...

Comment: Not an answer, but keeping your eye on http://kangax.github.com/es5-compat-table/es6/ might be interesting if you do decide to wait for the old browsers to die.

Comment: For anyone interested in this today: You can now use babeljs to https://babeljs.io/docs/learn-es6/#let-const to get cross-browser let functionality, and chrome 42 now supports the let keyword!

Comment: gkiely Babel is a compiler, not a polyfill.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is *absolutely no way* to mimic / shim a keyword in ECMAscript. So you either choose to totally go with it (which might be a very bad idea at present) or you can't use it yet.

As you might know, `let` is part of *ECMAscript Next* / *Harmony* and at best, its just available as *experimental feature* in some browsers. Even if `let` is a very stable feature, *ES.Next* spec is still in flux even. Go play with it, but it really makes no sense to rely on it *imho*.

Comment: Good answer and advice, confirmed what I thought. As Crocker said about ES5: maybe our children will use it.

Comment: I think ES6 features will see wide use in node.js a few years ahead of browsers.

Comment: @jAndy you might be interested in the solution I posted

Comment: Can't you use babel or another compiler or pre-compiler? Don't know what to call these things.

Comment: Agreed, doesn't Babble 'mimic'/translate ES6 keywords in ES5? This was originally posted in 2012 so maybe Babble wasn't a thing at the time?

Answer (score 24):

Let me quote what I just read on *[You Don't Know JS: Scope & Closures - Appendix B: Polyfilling Block Scope](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/scope%20&%20closures/apB.md)*

**PS: This is licensed under [Creative Commons CC BY-NC-ND 3.0](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-nd/3.0/) so it is OK to share it as long as the reference is mentioned**

### Large quote ahead:

Consider the following example

```
{
 let a = 2;
 console.log( a ); // 2
}

console.log( a ); // ReferenceError
```

This will work great in ES6 environments. But can we do so pre-ES6? catch is the answer.

```
try{throw 2}catch(a){
 console.log( a ); // 2
}
console.log( a ); // ReferenceError
```

Whoa! That’s some ugly, weird looking code. We see a try/catch that appears to forcibly throw an error, but the “error” it throws is just a value 2, and then the variable declaration that receives it is in the catch(a) clause. Mind: blown.

That's right, the catch clause has block-scoping to it, which means it can be used as a polyfill for block scope in pre-ES6 environments.

"But...", you say. "...no one wants to write ugly code like that!" That's true. No one writes (some of) the code output by the CoffeeScript compiler, either. That's not the point.

The point is that tools can transpile ES6 code to work in pre-ES6 environments. You can write code using block-scoping, and benefit from such functionality, and let a build-step tool take care of producing code that will actually work when deployed.

This is actually the preferred migration path for all (ahem, most) of ES6: to use a code transpiler to take ES6 code and produce ES5-compatible code during the transition from pre-ES6 to ES6.

Comment: If I ever need to explain to someone what a hack is, I'll remember this! In the mean time, you made my day, thanks!

Comment: Holy cow, that's an incredibly clever, and hideous solution. But it works!